# Run application/activity at first time

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to recognize first launch of my application or activity.

At this time I need to get some information from server create local database and save info to it. What is the best way to do this?

1. Create any preferences for example `FirstLaunch` and set `true` \ `false` to it.
2. Check whether my database exists or not.
3. Something else?

PS. All server calls must be into one transaction. Ormlite supports transactions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "create database at first run"-purpose, you should use an [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which offers you the [`onCreate()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) that is called when:

> [...] the database is created for the first time.

The Database-file itself will be created for you (you don't have to do this manually). In this method, you can then perform actions like populating your database with standard entry's.

---

If you want to populate the database with informations you get from your server, there might be a problem when there is no Internet-connection available.

In this case, I would check if there is a connection available:

- If there is, get your informations.
- If not, show a Toast or some other notification to inform the user.

To determine if your Database has be populated with the standard entry's, you can use the database-version which is also provided by the `SQLiteDatabase`-class:

- When you first create your Database-object, you call
  `SQLiteOpenHelper`s constructor and pass it `0` as the Database
  version.
- If you successfully populated your database, you use
  [`setVersion()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setVersion%28int%29) to alter it to `1`.
- Later in the [`onOpen()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onOpen%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29), which is called when the
  database is opened, you can check if the database was populated by
  using the [`getVersion()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion%28%29).

  - If it is populated, call the super-method to open it.
  - If not, try populating it.

Further more, the `getReadableDatabase()` / `getWritableDatabase()`-methods should be called off the main-thread anyways because:

> Database upgrade may take a long time, you should not call this method
>   from the application main thread, including from
>   ContentProvider.onCreate().

So getting the informations from the Internet can take place in the `onCreate()` and in the `onOpen()`-method (if it wasn't successful at the first try). You can (for example) use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using ormlite as orm framework for my application. ormlite have class OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper, it overrides onCreate method. In this menthod I am creating my tables. You think this is a good place to make a call to server and populate my database? What about some collisions when I'm trying to get server info, for example internet connections problem or thomething else?

Comment: I updated my post to add some more research on this. Check if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply again. I got main idea of your reply. 1) - check database version 2) - if version equal 0 - populate database and set database version = 1, 3) If version 1 or higher open database for get some information. Right? You said that databse population precess must to be not in main thread. What about AsyncTask? I want to creat AsyncTask for database population and call it when i need, for example database upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you don't use the main-thread, it's fine. But some features of `AsyncTask` where introduced in API-Level 11 (for example the [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) ) so i wasn't sure if your application needed to run on devices with less then Android 3.0 But it will do just fine if you want to use it.

Comment: Trying your approach. After retrieving information from the server I set database version = 2. On next launch of my application, even on next call dbHelper method onUpgrade is invoking, all tables dpropps and retrieving info from server repeat agian. Maybe if first retrieving was successful store some flag in preferences?

Comment: You could do that or you override the `onUpgrade()`-method to only execute when the DB-version is `(start_version + 1) ++`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this problem with database:
Create database with MyDatabasaVersion table and store your version in a single row, for example db_version default value is 0. First time when the application starts you check the db_version if 0 you need to start the syncronisation, after it is finishing set the db_version to 1.

Comment: Interesting approach. What benefits in this way? I cat store some flag in preferences to recognize first launch. What about if I need to upgrade my database?

Comment: We are using this possibility on the mobile side. The server database usually updated by the users, after that the version number is grown in the server side. And when the client side starts the synchronization first step is to check the version, if versions are not equal then need to upgrade the local database.

Comment: In my case users have an account on server, my app just a client. Users can update database on server via web and via my app. To avoid unnecessary server calls I want store some data in local databse. In my case I can't check database version on server side.

Comment: If you don't want to sava the modified data locally in the phone, you can make the initialization easily with Preferences and store data in the DB (for example user informations).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be sharedpreferences. you can call it everywhere form the application context and you can put boolean values in it.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) are all Android storages.

Answer (score 0):

you should try first option `Create any preferences for example FirstLaunch and set true \ false to it.`